# Why does /index internally redirect to my index page?

Tags: apache

On my Mac's Apache server, `/index` redirects internally to my index page. This doesn't happen on my Ubuntu Apache server. Why? How can I make it not do that?

There's a route in a web app I work on that shows an index of all the articles on the site. This lives at `/index`. I just tried to set up a local copy of the project and discovered that on my machine, `/index` shows me the site's home page. After some testing, I discovered that this happens with any virtual host, not just this project.

Answer (score 0):

After a bright idea from a coworker, I tried seeing if `/cow` would serve `cow.html`. Aaand it does.

The problem is the `Multiviews` option. Removing that from the options directive in `httpd.conf` made everything work as expected again.